# Combining SignalR 2 with database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I have followed [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) tutorial and learned a simple messaging web application. This tutorial doesn't show anything about how to add messages to database and show previous messages to the users. 
The core code in the tutorial is this :

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>
@section scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            $('#message').focus();
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

If I'm using EF Code-first and I have a Comment class like this :

```
 public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
    }
```

And If I have a Comment controller like this :

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CommentID, UserName, CommentText")] Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(comment);
}
```

I know I need to add some ajax code to display previous messages and send a new message, but I don't know what to write.. Can you tell me how I can write AJAX queries to post data to database and list previous messages? Any help or hints are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: have you added `app.MapSignalR();` to your `startup`-class?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server use this

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a separate controller. You can persist messages in the ChatHub class. Save messages to the database in `ChatHub.Send` method, and display previous messages to the new users by overriding `ChatHub.OnConnected` hub event - call `addNewMessageToPage` for the newly connected user.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);

        var comment = new Comment
        {
            CommentID = Guid.NewGuid(), // or find a way to autoincrement an int 
            UserName = name,
            CommentText = message
        }
        db.Comments.Add(comment); 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var comments = db.Comments.ToList(); // some sort of cache would be good here
        foreach(var comment in comments)
        {
            Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionID).addNewMessageToPage(comment.UserName, comment.CommentText);
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will really appreciate if you tell this with some piece of code.. I'm not good at programming so some piece of code can really work. Thanks.

Comment: It gives error : `OnConnected()': not all code paths return a value`  Thanks

Comment: Answer updated, but it still won't compile if you don't add `db` implementation.